# fusionCharts data from database in charts

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, charts, fusioncharts

I'm trying to get data from my database into a chart. The charts i'm using are from fusioncharts. If i print the row_cnt's they give me the correct information but in the table it gives me the wrong/no information.

```
$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
}
?>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>FusionCharts XT - Column 2D Chart - Data from a database</title>
    <script src="includes/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
<?php
$result = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email");
$result2 = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE status='1'");
$result3 = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE status='0'");

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$row_cnt2 = $result2->num_rows;
$row_cnt3 = $result3->num_rows;

// If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON strin

if ($result) {

// The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data

$arrData = array(
  "chart" => array
  (
    "caption" => "Aantal geregistreerde emails",
    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
    "showValues" => "0",
    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
  )
);

$arrData["data"] = array();

// Push the data into the array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
array_push($arrData["data"], array(
  "label" => 'active emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt,
  )
);
}
```

1. row_cnt gives me the total amount of emails
2. row_cnt2 gives me the total active emails
3. row_cnt3 gives me the total inactive/signedoff emails

in the chart it only gives me the total registered emails (row_cnt) and when i want to try to add the other 2 in the chart its not giving me any information. The bar with the total registered emails is also display twice. Someone know what im doing wrong or how to do this?

I want to display 3 different bars 1 needs to be the total registered emails bar number 2 needs to be the active ones and bar number 3 the inactive ones.

Comment: In your while loop, you are iterating over `$result3`. But you are pushing `$row_cnt` into the array every time. Could that be the problem? Try to write `"value" => $row['...something else...'], ...`

Comment: @peter_the_oak its a  part of the problem but i want to display 3 different bars i just edited my question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should simply push the three values `$row_cnt`, `$row_cnt2` and `$row_cht3` one after another.

Look at this:

```
// The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data

// First, add the chart array that describes the chart itself.

$arrData = array(
  "chart" => array
  (
    "caption" => "Aantal geregistreerde emails",
    ...
    ...
    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
  )
);

// Second, we add the values displayed by the bars.
$arrData["data"] = array();

// In this code example, we add the values each by each as they are available in three single variables.

// 1. Total:
array_push($arrData["data"], array(
  "label" => 'total emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt
));

// 2. Active:
array_push($arrData["data"], array(
  "label" => 'active emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt2
));

// 3. Active:
array_push($arrData["data"], array(
  "label" => 'inactive emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt3
));
```

But maybe you need to loop, as the number of processed values could change and you need to be flexible. In that case I recommend to collect the values in a separate array first and then loop the separate array. Like this:

```
...

// Second, we add the values displayed by the bars.
$arrData["data"] = array();

// In this code example, we for an array first and are able to loop over it.
$myBarArray = array();

// 1. Total:
$myBarArray[] = array(
  "label" => 'total emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt
);
// 2. Active:
$myBarArray[] = array(
  "label" => 'active emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt2
);
// 3. Active:
$myBarArray[] = array(
  "label" => 'inactive emails',
  "value" => $row_cnt3
);

// Now we can loop this array, or pass it to a further function or whatever:
foreach ($myBarArray as $bar) {
    $arrData["data"][] = $bar;
}
```

Either way, iterating over `$result` as in your question does not seem to be the right way.

Also please note the syntax with `[]` instead of `array_push()`, which sometimes is more readable.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks this helped me out a lot!